# skipping incompatible Library

Tags: c++, linux

I have some issues while linking library.

I have one library libipc.so which is compile using c Compiler

now I have one code which is in c++ I am running that code like

```
g++ -L /home/pcadmin/Desktop/Project -o output main.o task.o -lipc
```

but it is giving error like

```
skipping incompatible /home/pcadmin/Desktop/Project/libipc.so when searching for -lipc
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lipc
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Is the library built for 64-bit and your system is 32-bit, or the other way around? Or built for a different CPU or operating system?

Comment: Yes it is built for some other CPU

Comment: You can't link code from different architectures, hence "skipping incompatible"